# How do i replace the charfield with a checkbox in django admin

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, admin

ok, here goes. The tapStatus variable is used to decide whether or not this item gets pasted onto the website - it's a simple on off. I'm trying to make the admin page more user-friendly - right now I just use the charfield to accept a 1 or a 0, but a checkbox would be more appropriate. Can I modify the admin page to show a checkbox instead of the text box?

```
class beer(models.Model):
tapStatus = models.CharField(max_length=1)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.tapStatus
beerdescription = models.CharField(max_length=400)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.beerdescription
beerStyle = models.CharField(max_length=5)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.beerStyle
beerabv = models.CharField(max_length=5)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.beerabv
beername = models.CharField(max_length=40)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.beername
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BooleanField`. Here is an example:

```
class beer(models.Model):
    tapStatus = models.BooleanField(_('tap status'), default=False,
            help_text=_('decide whether or not this item gets pasted onto the website'))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.tapStatus)
    beerdescription = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.beerdescription
    beerStyle = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.beerStyle
    beerabv = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.beerabv
    beername = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.beername
```

Comment: you guys are brilliant, I'm going to get on it - let you know how it works out

Comment: magnificent, I truly appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield):

> ```
> class BooleanField(**options)
> A true/false field.
> The default form widget for this field is a CheckboxInput.
> If you need to accept null values then use NullBooleanField instead.
> ```